# How to input dynamic column names in a table from user?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I really want to know if it is possible to get dynamically column names from user .. and also if we create as many column as user wants with dynamic column name.

Comment: Can you expand please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us help you, please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61230945/edit) your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).